# odoo one2many acts like many2many

Tags: python, odoo

I created a relationship one2many/many2one:

```
class dev_person(Model):
    _name = "dev.person"
    _description = "Person"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Person', size=128, required=True),
        'properties': fields.many2one('dev.property', 'property_id', select=True),
       }

class dev_property(Model):
    _name = "dev.property"
    _description = "Property"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Property', size=128, required=True),
        'property_id': fields.one2many('dev.person', 'properties'),
       }
```

I want that one dev_person record can be linked with only one dev_property, but that is not the case. I am able to create two person records with the same name and different property, and I don't wont that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is confusing. Looking at your models, one `dev_person` record can indeed be linked with only one `dev_property`. At the same time it is true that you are "able to create two person records with the same name and different property" - this have nothing to do with the many2one relationship. If you create two people with the same name they are still two completely different `dev_person` objects. They are not the same person. Of course you can link them with different `dev_property`s.

If you want to block this, declare the `name` field unique. That way you won't be able to create two people with the same name (make sure this is indeed what you want, since in real life there are different people with the same name).

```
class dev_person(Model):
    _name = "dev.person"
    _description = "Person"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Person', size=128, required=True),
        'properties': fields.many2one('dev.property', 'property_id', select=True),
       }

    _sql_constraints = [
        (
            'dev_person_name_uniq',
            'unique(name)',
            "You can't have two people with the same name!",
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: I see your point. This is just a demo module, I am trying to get how things work. Instead of name, it could be ID_number, or something that has more sense...However, I added this constraint, but I still can create duplicate names...

Comment: Point is, one person should not be able to have two different properties, disable adding new record with same name and different record

Comment: Make sure there are no people with duplicate names already when you update your module, or the unique constraint will fail.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understood that,you want to person and property. And every person must have one property. No two persons can have same Name.

Confusing part is:-

- Then why did you define **one2many** field in **dev.property** with reference
  to **dev.person**

If your intention is to view the persons linked to this property you can use one2many functional field.

For this please try this code:-

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
class dev_person(osv.osv):
_name = "dev.person"
_description = "Person"
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Person', size=128, required=True),
    'properties': fields.many2one('dev.property', 'property_id', select=True),
   }
_sql_constraints = [
    ('name_uniq','unique(name)', 'You cannot have two people with the same name !')
    ]


class dev_property(osv.osv):
_name = "dev.property"
_description = "Property"
def _compute_persons(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    ''' This function will automatically computes the persons related to particular property.'''
    result = {}
    person_obj = self.pool.get('dev.person')
    for person_data in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        person_ids = person_obj.search(cr, uid, [('standard_id', '=', person_data.id)], context=context)
        result[person_data.id] = person_ids
    return result
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Property', size=128, required=True),
    'person_ids': fields.function(_compute_persons, method=True, relation='dev.person', type="one2many", string='Persons'),
   }
```

Hope this helps.